# How to pass user consent to AdMob (GDPR)

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads

I'm using AdMob to serve ads to users in EU. The documentation states that I  can pass the user consent status by the following line of code:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder() .AddExtra("npa", "1") .Build();
```

The problem is that this line does not compile. There is no such function as AddExtra on the AdRequst object.  I do use the latest AdMob library available.

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
```

So, how do I actually pass this "npa" value to AdMob.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add npa using `addNetworkExtrasBundle` method which like bellow

```
Bundle bundleExtra = new Bundle();
        bundleExtra.putString("npa", "1");

        AdRequest addRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, bundleExtra)
                .build();
```

And also please check bellow official link
 https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#forward_consent_to_the_google_mobile_ads_sdk

Comment: Great!  My bad I didn't see that. I was looking at the wrong SDK (Unity). Thanks!

Comment: How to add addNetworkExtrasBundle for admob and adcolony ads boths ? Like .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdColonyAdapter.class, AdColonyBundleBuilder.build()) along with admob network extras ?